# How to resolve localhost in PHP inside a docker image?

Tags: php, docker, dns

I am trying to resolve host names from within PHP that is running inside a docker container.

It works for FQDNs off of the internet (e.g. "stackoverflow.com") and plain hostnames resolved by my local router (e.g. "mytv") - basically DNS. It does not work for entries of the /etc/hosts file:

```
docker run -it php:7-alpine php -r "var_dump(dns_get_record('localhost'));";
array(0) {
}
```

But dns_get_record() can resolve from /etc/hosts, because  Doing the same on my Linux host machine, resolving localhost works:

```
php -r "var_dump(dns_get_record('localhost'));";
array(2) {
  [0]=>
  array(5) {
    ["host"]=>
    string(9) "localhost"
    ["class"]=>
    string(2) "IN"
    ["ttl"]=>
    int(0)
    ["type"]=>
    string(1) "A"
    ["ip"]=>
    string(9) "127.0.0.1"
  }
  [1]=>
  array(5) {
    ["host"]=>
    string(9) "localhost"
    ["class"]=>
    string(2) "IN"
    ["ttl"]=>
    int(0)
    ["type"]=>
    string(4) "AAAA"
    ["ipv6"]=>
    string(3) "::1"
  }
}
```

Do I need to adapt some PHP configuration inside the Docker image?

P.S. The PHP versions differ slights - I do not think this is the root cause.

```
docker run -it php:7-alpine php -v
PHP 7.4.16 (cli) (built: Apr  1 2021 15:50:12) ( NTS )
Copyright (c) The PHP Group
Zend Engine v3.4.0, Copyright (c) Zend Technologies
```

```
php -v
PHP 7.4.9 (cli) (built: Oct 26 2020 15:17:14) ( NTS )
Copyright (c) The PHP Group
Zend Engine v3.4.0, Copyright (c) Zend Technologies
    with Zend OPcache v7.4.9, Copyright (c), by Zend Technologies
```

Comment: The docker container of course has a `/etc/hosts` file with an line for localhost and `ping localhost` works.

Comment: Interestingly, `nslookup localhost` also shows different behavior on the physical host versus inside the Docker container. Only on the host machine, localhost is resolved.

Comment: What does the hosts file have for localhost?  It may be that if you change it to 172.17.0.1 (or whatever is your docker ip) then it may resolve.

Comment: The real question is _why_ you want to resolve `localhost` inside of a container, and what you expect that to actually point to. Neither of those things are likely what you want them to be inside the container.

Comment: Why? I want my application to behave the same way inside a docker container than on a physical host or a VM. Even if I do not intend to make a connection to the resulting IP address.